# How do I get rid of Grey Space on Xcode 11 for iPhone X/newer?

Tags: ios, uikit, constraints, scrollview

I have a horizontal scroll view in place.
Constraints are set to 0 (SuperView) for Scroll View, BackGround, PathView.

Content shows correctly EXCEPT on the left and right ends of scroll, I get this grey space.
I assume it has something to do with Face ID phones having the notch. It doesn't do this on iPhone 8/plus sized phones.

I have also turned off bounce effects and its still there.

Image for reference:
[image]

Comment: Don't use superview constraints. Attach your views to the safe area margins instead.

Comment: The black is a background image which I want to stretch completely. If I use safe area margins with the constraints, won't it add more border?